Announcing the October–November 2024 topic challenge: Gabriela Mistral
In accordance with our meta agreement to have topic challenges
and a later meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month,
it is time to announce the October–November 2024 topic challenge.
Based on the number of votes (+5), our next topic challenge will be
the works of Gabriela Mistral

What's a topic challenge?
See the meta posts linked above, and also this main Meta post.
In short, during October and November 2024 you are invited to try to get hold of one or more of the works by Gabriela Mistral, read them, and ask or answer questions about them.
Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during October and November too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.
How can I take part?
By getting hold of one or more of the works by Gabriela Mistral and

asking good questions about it or
answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
submitting a book review to our Tumblr blog.

Questions about these works should be tagged gabriela-mistral and spanish-language (and a tag for any book-length work).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.
Below is Clara Díaz Sanchez's
presentation:

The works of Gabriela Mistral (1889–1957)
Gabriela Mistral was the first Latin-American author, and the only female Latin-American, to be awarded the Nobel Prize for Literature. Although famous in Spanish speaking countries, she was rather overshadowed by her near-contemporary and close friend, Pablo Neruda, and is considerably less well-known in the rest of the world.
In her lifetime she published four books of poetry: Desolation, Tenderness, Clearcut, and Winepress, and a fifth, The Poem of Chile, was published posthumously. As the Poetry Foundation page notes:

Mistral defended the rights of children, women, and the poor; the
freedoms of democracy; and the need for peace in times of social,
political, and ideological conflicts, not only in Latin America but in
the whole world. She always took the side of those who were mistreated
by society: children, women, Native Americans, Jews, war victims,
workers, and the poor, and she tried to speak for them through her
poetry

Universal themes, of especial relevance to the difficult times we are currently living in.
Ursula K. Le Guin was strongly drawn to the poems of Mistral, and spent five years on a labour of love, preparing a selection of Mistral's poems and personally translating them  into English. Le Guin described the result as:

There is no other voice in poetry like Mistral’s, from the miraculous
clarity of her rounds and lullabyes, to the fiery rage of her love
poems, to the dark complexity and visionary power of her late work. I
hope this book may begin to restore this amazing poet to the
recognition she deserves. Most of all I hope it comes to the hands of
readers who will love her.


What's next?

Vote for the next topic challenge or propose your own!


List of all questions posted in this topic challenge

Why did Gabriela Mistral adopt a pseudonym instead of using her real name? by Rand al'Thor, 05/10/2024 (HNQ, 2,387 view, 11 votes, 3 answers).
Who are "the great Florentine" and "Mireya"? by Rand al'Thor, 06/10/2024 (HNQ, 450 views, 2 votes, 1 answer).
Why is the translation of estanque as millpond justified? by Tsundoku, 02/11/2024 (HNQ, 1,316 views, 11 votes, 3 answers).
Why the son's wheat? by Tsundoku, 04/11/2024 (105 views, 3 votes, 1 answer).
Did a real-world event inspire Mistral's "The Revolution of the Plants"? by Clara Díaz Sanchez, 05/11/2024 (58 views, 5 votes, no answers).
Why is the translation of cilicio as lash justified? by Tsundoku, 08/11/2024 (77 views, 2 votes, 1 answer).
Why did Mistral choose these animals to compare with the sun in her poem "Dos Himnos"? by Peter Shor, 09/11/2024 (74 views, 4 votes, 1 answer).
The three trees in Mistral's "Tres árboles" by Tsundoku, 10/11/2024 (68 views, 3 votes, 1 answer).
What are the thousands of worlds in Mistral's Meciendo? by Tsundoku, 11/11/2024 (109 views, 2 votes, 1 answer).
What's with the rat and the bride in Gabriela Mistral's La rata? by Tsundoku, 14/11/2024 (64 views, 2 views, no answers).
Gabriela Mistral's La pajita by Tsundoku, 17/11/2024 (HNQ, 317 views, 5 votes, 1 answer).
Why Agamemnon? (Gabriela Mistral: Ronda de los colores) by Tsundoku, 19/11/2024 (HNQ, 414 views, 4 votes, 3 answers).
What sort of love and epiphany are meant in Mistral's Dos ángeles? by Tsundoku, 23/11/2024 (42 views, 3 votes, 1 answer).
Who or what is Gabriela Mistral's death-girl? by Tsundoku, 24/11/2024 (25 views, 0 votes, no answers).
Gabriela Mistral's La flor del aire by Tsundoku, 25/11/2024 (21 views, 2 votes, no answers).
Is Gabriela Mistral referring to a specific historical use of asbestos in South America? by Tsundoku, 27/11/2024 (39 views, 3 votes, 1 answer).
Who or what are the Pelayos in Gabriela Mistral's poem Ronda de los metales? by Tsundoku, 28/11/2024 (43 views, 1 vote, 2 answers).
Who are Catalina and Teresa in Gabriela Mistral's poem Vieja? by Tsundoku, 30/11/2024 (13 views, 1 vote, 1 answer submitted minutes before the end of the challenge).


The highest-voted of these are Why did Gabriela Mistral adopt a pseudonym instead of using her real name? and Why is the translation of estanque as millpond justified? with a score of 11 at the end of November.
The most viewed is Why did Gabriela Mistral adopt a pseudonym instead of using her real name?, with approximately 2,387 views by the end of November.
Five out of 18 questions became hot network questions (HNQ).
14 questions received at least one answer. 21 answers were submitted.

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: Selected Poems of Gabriela Mistral, translated by Ursula K. Le Guin by Tsundoku, 30/11/2024.

and Q.18 also went HNQ, but after the challenge finished.
